# How to free up more storage (upgrading to 4.2 made me lose 6GB)?

Tags: internal-storage, 4.2-jelly-bean, file-system

So this morning, I bought a new game and it required a large file download. I went to download it and a message told me that I had 0mb of space remaining.  This seemed odd to me because last time I checked I had plenty of space.

I looked at my storage and saw a little over 6GB in Apps and a little over 6GB in Misc.  I uninstalled 2 games which both had large files (around 2GB each).  After uninstalling, my App storage updated to what is shown in the image (1.82GB). The Misc storage did not change at all after uninstalling the apps.

I understand that Android now has a `/sdcard` and a `/sdcard/0` for the multi-user feature. There are many duplicate directories in these two locations. For example, there exists both `/sdcard/Downloads` and `/sdcard/0/Downloads`. The `/sdcard/0/downloads` has all the downloads from *before* I updated to 4.2, and `/sdcard/downloads` has all the downloads *since* I updated to 4.2. This makes me think that `/sdcard/0` is like a backup, but from the research I've done, it seems like the multi-user support effects more than just this sdcard stuff that I'm seeing (something about emulated storage). Right now, I am trying to free up as much storage as I can, but I get so confused when going into the file system now.

**Questions:**

1. What is this Misc stuff? More specifically, what is the obb and 0 that is taking up all my storage?
2. What can I delete to simplify this mess and free up storage?

[image: Internal Storage]

[image: Misc Files]

Comment: That is the feature of JB's multi-user accounts...

Comment: @t0mm13b Why would you make the images smaller? I can't see them.

Comment: @StephenWatkins reason to minimize vertical scrolling and to make it easier, have amended to include linky to a bigger image.. :)

Answer (score 2):

No, it will not duplicate your files. However, there are some files that will not be deleted, like system files and some other software data.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by the second half of your answer about "system files and other software data"? It's not very clear what you mean there, and seems to imply (currently) that it *does* cause some data to be duplicated.

Comment: this doesn't really answer my question(s). If you understand what is going on in the situation I explained above, please explain it.